# Offline Mapbox Tiles with GoogleMap addTileOverlay()

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im trying to add offline maps to my application using [MapBoxOfflineTileProvider](https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons/blob/master/src/com/cocoahero/android/gmaps/addons/mapbox/MapBoxOfflineTileProvider.java). However this library class is made for v2 and Im using v3 of "GoogleMap". Is it still possible to provide a .mbtiles file with your own tiles and show the tiles offline?

My code looks like this:

```
private GoogleMap gMap;
public void changeMapType(int maptype) {
    String overlayString = "";
    if (gMap == null) {
      return;
    }
   //Code remove here...
    File myMBTiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyRoutes/countries.mbtiles");
    TileOverlayOptions opts = new TileOverlayOptions();
    MapBoxOfflineTileProvider provider = new MapBoxOfflineTileProvider(myMBTiles);
opts.tileProvider(provider);

    mSelectedTileOverlay = gMap.addTileOverlay(opts);
    provider.close();
}
```

Nothing happens, there are no tiles shown on the screen. It works fine with online tiles.

I know there is a solution with OSM, but I specifically want to keep using the GoogleMap class, since my app is fully build on it.

The sample countries.mbtiles comes from [this place](https://github.com/klokantech/vector-tiles-sample#user-content-create-vector-mbtiles-with-pbf-inside). It should contain tiles for my location, since I live in Europe and the map is centered on my location.

Comment: There is no Google Maps API v3 for Android, current version is v2 (v3 is for JavaScript). You may want to take a look at my project here https://github.com/antoniocarlon/MapUtils It allows to load MBTiles files into Google Maps API Android v2

Comment: Okay my bad! I think this will work, awesome. I'll try now @antonio

Comment: @antonio, do you know how I can resolve the issue where my lines and circles drawn on the map are hidden or rather below the overlay?

Comment: @antonio, just solved this with polyOpt.zIndex(99). :)